# cakePHP & Boostrap insert html code into form - radio - option

Tags: html, forms, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, helper

Is it possible to insert custom html code into a options name with Bootstraps formhelper?

```
<?php
  echo $this->BootstrapForm->input('where', array(
      'options' => array('1' => 'foo'),
      'type' => 'radio'
      ));

?>
```

I would like it to be

```
<?php
  echo $this->BootstrapForm->input('where', array(
      'options' => array('1' => '<span class="italic">f</span>oo'),
      'type' => 'radio'
      ));

?>
```

But when I insert the code it's being stripped from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure which BoostrapForm helper you are using, but have you considered putting a flag escape as false ?

```
<?php
  echo $this->BootstrapForm->input('where', array(
      'options' => array('1' => '<span class="italic">f</span>oo'),
      'type' => 'radio',
      'escape' => false,
      ));

?>
```